# How to add evaluated results to 2d list

Tags: list, lisp, common-lisp, vertices, slime

I'm trying to make a list of 3d coordinates of a sphere vertices, starting with ((0 0 1) ...) like this:

```
(defvar spherelatamount 7)
(defvar spherelonamount 8)
(defparameter sphereverticeslist
  (make-list (+ 2 (* (- spherelatamount 2) spherelonamount))))
(setf (elt sphereverticeslist 0) '(0 0 1))
```

Trying to add next point

```
(setf (elt sphereverticeslist 1)
      '(0 (sin (/ pi 6)) (cos (/ pi 6))))
```

this gives result

```
((0 0 1) (sin (/ pi 6)) (cos (/ pi 6)) ...)
```

while I need:

```
((0 0 1) (0 0.5 0.866) ...)
```

i.e. evaluated sin and cos. How do I achieve that? Thanks.

wrote:

```
(defvar spherelatamount 7)
(defvar spherelonamount 8)
(defparameter sphereverticeslist
  (make-list (+ 2 (* (- spherelatamount 2) spherelonamount))))
(setf (elt sphereverticeslist 0)
      '(0 0 1))
(setf (elt sphereverticeslist 1)
     '(0 (sin (/ pi 6)) (cos (/ pi 6))))
```

expecting:

```
((0 0 1) (0 0.5 0.866) ...)
```

Comment: If you're going to be indexing the collection numerically, it's generally better to use an array rather than a list.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting the list prevents evaluation of everything in the list, so you just insert the literal values.

Call `list` to create a list with evaluated values.

```
(setf (elt sphereverticeslist 1) (list 0 (sin (/ pi 6)) (cos (/ pi 6))))
```

If you have a mixture of literal and evaluated values, you can use backquote/comma.

```
(setf (elt sphereverticeslist 1) `(0 ,(sin (/ pi 6)) ,(cos (/ pi 6))))
```

Comment: @adabsurdum: I don't think backquoted forms are literals in general.  Certainly the spec does not say they are that I can see.  Obviously `\`(x)` is allowed to be, but I would be astonished if, in `(let ((x (cons 1 1))) \`(,x ,x))` I think it would be very surprising if the value was a literal.  Indeed, if it was the case that backquote always made literals, then any object can be made literal by `\`,`.

Comment: @ignisvolens -- After looking through the CL spec it is clear that you are right about this. I guess I was remembering that _Scheme_ implementations are allowed to transform, e.g., `(let ((x (cons 1 1))) \`(,x ,x))` into `(quote ((1 . 1) (1 . 1)))`.

Comment: @adabsurdum  Can you cite the section of R7RS that allows that? I think it might be allowed if you did `(let ((x '(1 . 1))) ...)` but not if you call `cons`.

Comment: @Barmar -- R7RS and R6RS have almost the same language. From R7RS 4.2.8. Quasiquotation: _"A quasiquote expression may return either newly allocated, mutable objects or literal structure for any structure that is constructed at runtime during the evaluation of the expression."_

Comment: But `x` is not constructed during the evaluation of the quasiquote expression. It's constructed by the let-binding `(x (cons 1 1))`

Comment: @Barmar -- I think that you are right. I guess that Scheme implementations are not allowed to transform `(let ((x (cons 1 1))) \`(,x ,x))` into `(quote ((1 . 1) (1 . 1)))`, but they are allowed to transform `\`(,(cons 1 1) ,(cons 1 1))` this way.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using an inefficient 3-element list, consider using a structure to represent the coordinates instead. This stores the values more compactly, gives you O(1) accessors and setters instead of a list's O(N), and lets you use symbolic names for components of the coordinates, leading to more readable code. Something like:

```lisp
(defstruct sphere (distance 0.0 :type float) ; r
                  (polar-angle 0.0 :type float) ; θ
                  (azimuth 0.0 :type float)) ; φ

;; Make a list of sphere coordinates
(defparameter sphere-vertices-list
  (list (make-sphere :distance 0.0 :polar-angle 0.0 :azimuth 1.0)
        (make-sphere :distance 0.0 :polar-angle (sin (/ pi 6)) :azimuth (cos (/ pi 6)))))

;; Set and get a value
(setf (sphere-distance (first sphere-vertices-list)) 0.5)
(print (sphere-distance (first sphere-vertices-list)))
;; etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to evaluate the calls:

```
(defvar spherelonamount 8)
(defparameter sphereverticeslist
   (make-list (+ 2 (* (- spherelatamount 2) spherelonamount))))
(setf (elt sphereverticeslist 0) '(0 0 1))
(setf (elt sphereverticeslist 1)
      `(0 ,(sin (/ pi 6)) ,(cos (/ pi 6))))
```